# Can't send params to Spring get method

Tags: angularjs, spring

I'm trying to make a get request with some params to a Spring get method. I'm using angular to make a call and this is my example

```
var apiUrl =  'api/trupci-filter';

    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiUrl,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "application/json"
        },
        data:   {
            klasa: "1",
            promjer:"1",
            duzina: "1" 
        }
    }
    console.log(req)
    return $http(req)
```

And this is my get method in Spring:

```
 @GetMapping("/trupci-filter")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Trupci>> getTrupciWithFilter(
        @RequestParam(value = "klasa", required = false) String klasa,
        @RequestParam(value = "promjer", required = false) String promjer,
        @RequestParam(value = "duzina", required = false) String duzina )
```

The call is successful but the params are always null. I can't find any solution to this simple thing and I'm losing my mind.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments: data is used to send a request **body**. GET requests don't have a body. Read the documentation I linked to find out what to use instead.

Comment: Just found out the answer...It should not be "data", it should be "params" !!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET request can't have `data` element, its for request body like for HTTP POST, PUT etc. Please use `params` for query string parameters.

```
var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiUrl,
        params:   {
            klasa: "1",
            promjer:"1",
            duzina: "1" 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since GET requests don't have a content body, it is foolish to add a `Content-Type` header.